# Is it possible to drive 4 seven segment display with MSP430G2231?

Tags: msp430, multiplexer, 7segmentdisplay

I'm trying to teach myself electronics and my goal is to create a digital clock with 4 digits.

I have  an MSP430G2231 which has only 8 available ports as far as I can tell.

I saw some methods for driving multiple seven segment displays, like using a multiplexer or transistors. But it doesn't seem possible with MSP430G2231 because of it's lack of ports.

Am I wrong? Or could it be done? If yes, how?

Comment: msp430 14 pin DIPS have 10 ports P1.0 to P1.7 and P2.6 and p2.7

Comment: @jsolarski - He would at least need 11: 7 for the segments and 4 for the digits. (And maybe a few buttons)

Comment: @stevenh good time to use the new 20 pin msp430g2x52 or msp430g2x12? 16 pins for GPIO +8K programming space and 256b ram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Leon says you can use an I/O expander, or even better a LED display driver. In the past I've used the MAX7219, but this is a 5V device, for 3.3V you have to go to MAX6950.  This can drive up to five 7-segment digits (the 6951 can do 8), so that may be suitable for your clock. It's controlled via SPI, so you only need 3 I/O pin of your controller. The driver does the multiplexing for you, has a BCD to 7-segment decoder and you can control brightness via software. One minor issue may be the package. The 7219 was available in DIL, but the 6950 only comes in a 0.635 mm pitch TSOP.

[image]

You say you don't want a crystal (why not?). For a clock you normally would use a crystal to get the required accuracy. But you can also work with the mains frequency, which over long term like months is even more accurate.

**edit**
Leon rightly remarks on the high price for the MAX6950. The MAX7219 is more affordable, but like I said it's a 5V device. Since you only need 3 lines to drive it you could easily add a few level shifters. A transistor will suffice, at least if you don't mind bit-banging the SPI (because it inverts the signal). If you want to use the on-chip SPI you need a non-inverting level shifter, like the [FXL4T245](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/pf/FX/FXL4T245.html) (difficult package though).

Alternatively, just buy an MSP430 with more I/O pins :-)

Comment: The MAX6950 costs $13.84 from Digi-Key!

Comment: So? It's not like he asked for cheap - he asked for possible.

Comment: @Leon - Yes, that's not cheap. I wonder why. It's a rather simple die, 17000 transistors. IIRC I bought the 7219 for 2.50 euros.

Comment: @Leon - I went looking around for other display drivers from Maxim, and I found that the MAX6955 (which you recommended [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2185/i2c-7seg-driver)) costs even twice as much! ($28)

Comment: It looks like Maxim got remarks from customers who found the max7219 too big, so they went from a 24 pin skinny DIP to a 16 pin QSOP (5 mm long vs. 30!). That's too little pins for the usual multiplexing like the max7219 uses, so the max6950 uses charlieplexing.

Answer (score 4):

I would use 2 x 74HC 595 shift registers 
I have tried the code example and schematic Here http://www.43oh.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=255 and it works with out an issue - I would suggest replacing the uln2003 with a few 2n2222 or 2n3909 npn transistor

[image]

```
    #include <msp430g2231.h>

unsigned int counter = 0;                   // Counter variable
unsigned int digitCounter = 0;            // Digit counter
unsigned char digit = 0;               // Single digit to be displayed
unsigned char bcd7digit[10] = {0x3F,0x06,0x5B,0x4F,0x66,0x6D,0x7D,0x07,0x7F,0x6F}; // BCD to 7 digit map
unsigned char digitSelector[4] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08}; // Digit selector map

void main(void)
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                 // Stop WDT

  P1OUT |= 0x01;                      // Port P1.0 will be used to latch
  P1DIR |= 0x01;

  USICTL0 |= USIPE6 + USIPE5 + USIMST + USIOE; // Out & clk enable, SPI Master
  USICTL1 |= USICKPH + USIIE;               // Counter interrupt, flag remains set
  USICKCTL = USIDIV_7 + USISSEL_2;          // /128 SMCLK
  USICTL0 &= ~USISWRST;                     // USI released for operation
  USICNT = USI16B;                           // Enable 16 bit

  CCTL0 = CCIE;                             // CCR0 interrupt enabled
  CCR0 = 500;                        //
  TACTL = TASSEL_2 + MC_1 + ID_3;           // SMCLK, upmode

  _bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);        // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupt
}

// Timer A0 interrupt service routine
#pragma vector = TIMERA0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A (void)
{   
  digitCounter++;                       // Increase digit counter
  digitCounter &= 0x03;                // Mask, counter range is 0-3
  digit = counter>>(4 * digitCounter);       // Shift digits right
  digit &= 0x0F;                      // Mask, we need first digit only
  USISRL = bcd7digit[digit];             // Get segments from the map
  USISRH = digitSelector[digitCounter];    //
  if(digitCounter == 0) {
     counter = _bcd_add_short(counter, 0x01);// Decimally increase counter's when on first digit
  }
  USICNT |= 16;                              // Start USI
}

// USI interrupt service routine
#pragma vector = USI_VECTOR
__interrupt void USI_TXRX (void)
{
  USICTL1 &= ~USIIFG;                     // Clear pending flag
  P1OUT &= ~0x01;                     // Latch data
  P1OUT |= 0x01;
}
```

Another Option would be using 4 x 74HC595 and use one each, for every 7segment you have this cuts the multiplexing and you can just send a serial string through the SPI interface or bit bang it. very similar as above. but uses less pins. Just an Idea

Answer (score 1):

I think it actually has 8 I/O pins (not ports, it has one port) available if you use a crystal, which is plenty for four multiplexed seven-segment displays if you use a suitable port expander. It might be sensible to use a device with more I/Os, though.

A suitable port expander is the PCF8575, which can be interfaced to the MSP430G2231 via I2C. It will give you 16 I/Os. It costs under $2.

Comment: I don't want to use any external crystal. Can I use the pins XIN, XOUT for my I/O purposes?

Comment: If you want any sort of accuracy a crystal is essential! Even if you dispense with it, you won't have enough outputs (you need 11).

Comment: yes you can use xin and xout they are labeled P2.6 and P2.7

Comment: @Leon - The PCF8575 is not very well suited as a LED driver. Maximum allowed device current is 100 mA, so if you want to drive 16 LEDs simultaneously (2 digits in @frbry's clock) you can only have 6 mA per LED

Comment: It would need some driver transistors.

Comment: @Leon - "some driver transistors". Yes, 16 of them. Plus 16 extra resistors. Hm. Wouldn't something like TPIC6C595 be more appropriate? Doesn't do I2C, but is easy enough to bit-bang. And you would two of them for 16 I/Os (they're cascadable), but at least you don't need all that chicken feed.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the USI(SPI) output to a 74HC164 shift-register, which can drive one piece of 7-segment display. The final bit from the first 74HC164 can be connected in cascade mode to another 74HC164, and then to another 74HC164...  So, with 4 pieces of 74HC164 in series, you just transmit 4 bytes from the USI to display 4 digits.

Please see http://singamicro-30-msp430g2231.blogspot.com/ on the USI.

Comment: A schematic would be useful. Also, blogs and external links go away so please include the main portion of the text in your answer and link to the blog as a reference. That keeps your answer relevant even if the content goes away.